# Can I power two GPUs (2x 8pin, 1x 8pin) with two PSU cables?

Tags: power-supply, power, gpu

I want to add one more GPU to my system. This GPU requires an 8-pin PCIE power connection but I'm all out. I am currently powering a GPU with two 8-pin cables each of which terminates in a 6-pin plug. So, I have 2x 6-pin plugs available. What I want to do is use a 2x 6-pin to 8-pin adapter to power the 2nd single 8-pin GPU.

In pictures - two of these cables powering two GPUs in parallel:

[image]

Two 8pins powering one GPU, and two of the 6-pin ends going into this adapter to power the second GPU:

[image: 6pin adapter]

Disclaimer: I understand that this is a fairly unorthodox method but I also know that 8-pin PCIE is rated to 150W, 6-pin to 75W, and PCIE slot to 75W. So in theory I'll have less than 300W draw on 300W spec plus there's PCIE power. I have an IR thermometer I can use to monitor wire temps. **Is there a flaw in my reasoning, am I overlooking something? Can I do this safely?**

Hardware info:
PSU: EVGA G2 Gold 1000W (single rail)
GPU1: ~142W draw / 166W TDP
GPU2: ~110W draw / 120W TDP

Comment: Just so long as the right voltage/current is provided by the connector pins and your PSU can handle the draw the only way you'll know is by trying ;)

Comment: You can splice a connection as many times as you want so long as your voltage and amperage of the PSU support your load.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried doing this and it has been stable and working. Wires do not get warm at all. YMMV so do it at your own risk.